# Binding drives me Crazy

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

Edit:

the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentShows}"  Grid.Row="1"/>
```

produces following Output:

```
 SilverlightHelloWorld.Deserialize.schedule
```

the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentShows.Today}"  Grid.Row="1"/>
```

nor

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentShows.Today.Date}"  Grid.Row="1"/>
```

produce any Error or ouput while being in debugmode.

Anysuggestions?

---

OldStatement:

I've got a quiet well complicated Example here,
the best will be, I am starting with my Code.

This is my Codebehind:

Mainpage.xaml.cs

```
schedule currentshows;
    public schedule CurrentShows
    {
        protected set
        {
            if (currentshows != value)
            {
                currentshows = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentShows");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return currentshows;
        }
    }
```

schedule.cs

```
[XmlRoot]
    public class schedule : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        DayCollection today;
        [XmlElement("DAY")]
        public DayCollection Today
        {
            set
            {
                if (today != value)
                {
                    today = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Today");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return today;
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }

    }
```

DayCollection.cs

```
    public class DayCollection : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        ObservableCollection<TimeCollection> timecol;
        [XmlElement("time")]
        public ObservableCollection<TimeCollection> TimeCol
        {
            set
            {
                if (timecol != value)
                {
                    timecol = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TimeCol");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return timecol;
            }
        }

        string date;
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "attr")]
        public string Date
        {
            set 
            {
                if (date != value)
                {
                    date = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Date");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return date;
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }

    }
```

I am trying to get the String-Property "Date" in my Xaml to Show-Up.
But I am just don't get any Solution.

I totally would appreciate any help here, Thanks in Advance !

Comment: First thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.

Comment: Isn't it standard? Well, I checked again, and turned them even up on error and it jsut compile fine. No Errors, no Warnings, no nothing.

Comment: No, not while compiling, while running.

Comment: Even running the program, nothing appears. Just To provide some xaml Code...                 `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentShows.Today.Date}"  Grid.Row="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Shows[0].ShowName}" />` Lasttextblock is properly filled, that ones above just doesn't show anything.

Comment: I can guarantee if you have a problem with your binding, it will be reported at debug time if you have your options set as demonstrated in that image.  So either your issue is elsewhere (most likely) or your installation of VS is bad (much less likely).  First thing to do is close and restart VS, and try again.

Comment: Sorry for that, it just was my mistake. But I still have got only one mistake (obviously) which doesn't handle with the Textbox which Bindings doesn't work at all. Its a Binding Expression Error with the TextBlock which binds to Shows[0].ShowName

Comment: Well, I actually don't know what you exactly want to, because I still don't get any error one the BindingExpression, but I simplified it a bit.

Comment: Where are you setting the DataContext in the xaml?

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` - Just on the Applications Page, so Root Element

Comment: `SilverlightHelloWorld.Deserialize.schedule` is an automatically generated type?  That's the output of the default implementation of ToString().  So the binding is setting the text of the textbox to CurrentShows.ToString().  You know where the binding is at, all you need to do is continue the path to the property of the type you want.

Comment: If you have no errors and you see nothing then it means that you have nothing in your model class

Comment: Well, thats what I am actually trying. Schedule.Today is an isntance of another Class, which Property Date is of type string. Using the above Xaml Code does not produce any output though debugging shows up, that there is a valid value. Not even schedule.Today produce a .ToString() Output.

Comment: Btw. using `CurrentShows.Today.TimeCol[0].Shows[0].ShowName` shows me the Result:
"Live with Regis and Kelly" but using the same code on Xaml just doesn't show anything. The Content will be produced after initalization. I think there will be my problem..

Comment: Well actually...the Problem was using once the false variable (lower case instead of upper case...) so PropertyChanged didn't trigger.

I could eat myself for that..

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code into a project and it works if you use this line instead to set up the TextBlock's binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Today.Date}"  Grid.Row="1"/>
```

but I cannot tell from your code how you are setting up the outer data binding. Here's what I included in the MainPage constructor

```
currentshows = new schedule();
currentshows.Today = new DayCollection();
currentshows.Today.Date = "hallo";
LayoutRoot.DataContext = currentshows;
```

where LayoutRoot is the parent of the TextBlock, i.e.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Today.Date}"/> 
</Grid>
```